# Store output of sapply into a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

how can I store the output of `sapply()` to a dataframe where the index value is stored in first column and its value in corresponding 2nd column. For illustration, I have shown only 2 elements here, but there are 110 columns in my data. "loan" is the data frame.

```
cols <- sapply(loan,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))                                                          
cols                                                                          
id                                                                               
0                                                                              
member_id                                                                             
7
```

I want output as:

```
var         value                             
id            0                                  
member_id     7
```

I know that sapply() returns a vector, but when I print the vector, values are printed along with its some "index" e.g., column name if applied on a data frame. So, now when I want to store it as a data frame with two columns where 1st column contains the index part and the second column contains the value, how can I do it?

Comment: I do not want to first save this column using write.csv and then again read it inside the code. I know the solution must be easy, but m stuck here and unable to think of anything.

Comment: can you give a reproducible example

Comment: cols <- sapply(loan,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))                                          cols                                                                                                              id   345           loan_amount       545

Comment: Please edit your original question to add any new information.

Comment: Why has the question been marked in negative value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to my question. For those who actually did understand my problem, this answer might make sense:

```
cols <- data.frame(sapply(loan ,function(x) sum(is.na(x))))                     

cols <- cbind(variable = row.names(cols), cols)
```

I wanted the `row.names` to be in a column of the same data frame corresponding to the values obtained from `sapply`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `stack`

```
stack(mylist)[2:1]
```

#### data

```
mylist <- list(df = 1, rf = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? 
Your original list:

```
L <- c("df",1,"rf",2)
L

[1] "df" "1"  "rf" "2"
```

As a data frame:

```
N <- length(L)
df <- data.frame( var = L[seq(1,N,2)], value = L[seq(2,N,2)] )
df

  var value
1  df     1
2  rf     2
```