# How to assign the output of a sapply loop to the original columns in a data frame without losing other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I a data frame with different columns that has string answers from different assessors, who used random upper or lower cases in their answers. I want to convert everything to lower case. I have a code that works as follows:

```
# Creating a reproducible data frame similar to what I am working with
dfrm <- data.frame(a = sample(names(islands))[1:20],
               b = sample(unname(islands))[1:20],
               c = sample(names(islands))[1:20],
               d = sample(unname(islands))[1:20],
               e = sample(names(islands))[1:20],
               f = sample(unname(islands))[1:20],
               g = sample(names(islands))[1:20],
               h = sample(unname(islands))[1:20])
# This is how I did it originally by writing everything explicitly:
dfrm1 <- dfrm
dfrm1$a <- tolower(dfrm1$a)
dfrm1$c <- tolower(dfrm1$c)
dfrm1$e <- tolower(dfrm1$e)
dfrm1$g <- tolower(dfrm1$g)
head(dfrm1) #Works as intended
```

The problem is that as the number of assessors increase, I keep making copy paste errors. I tried to simplify my code by writing a function for `tolower`, and used `sapply` to loop it, but the final data frame does not look like what I wanted:

```
# function and sapply:
dfrm2 <- dfrm
my_list <- c("a", "c", "e", "g")
my_low <- function(x){dfrm2[,x] <- tolower(dfrm2[,x])}
sapply(my_list, my_low) #Didn't work

# Alternative approach:
dfrm2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(my_list, my_low))
head(dfrm2) #Lost the numbers
```

What am I missing?

I know this must be a very basic concept that I'm not getting. There was [this question and answer that I simply couldn't follow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485428/store-output-of-sapply-into-a-data-frame), and [this one where my non-working solution simply seems to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907912/r-sapply-loop-to-replace-for-loop). Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to create a logical vector that selects the columns to change and run an apply function only over those columns.

```
# only choose non-numeric columns
changeCols <- !sapply(dfrm, is.numeric)

# change values of selected columns to lower case
dfrm[changeCols] <- lapply(dfrm[changeCols], tolower)
```

If you have other types of columns, say logical, you also could be more explicit regarding the types of columns that you want to change. For example, to select only factor and character columns, use.

```
changeCols <- sapply(dfrm, function(x) is.factor(x) | is.character(x))
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using `lapply` over `sapply` here? (Avoiding `as.data.frame`?)

Comment: `sapply` is a wrapper to `lapply` that uses `simplyfy2array` the final outpu in order to attempt to simplify the output to the greatest extent possible without losing information. This simplification, which takes some amount of computing, is not necessary here. All we want is to place the contents of the respective list item (a character variable) into its original slot.

Comment: Oh, by the way, it didn't work as `dfrm[changeCols] <- lapply(dfrm[changeCols], tolower)`, but worked as `dfrm[changeCols] <- lapply(changeCols, tolower)`. Could you edit to reflect? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure why `dfrm[changeCols] <- lapply(changeCols, tolower)` would work at all. If dfrm is a data.frame, it is a list and `dfrm[changeCols]` selects the list elements of interest. `lapply(dfrm[changeCols], FUN)` will run through each list item of interest and apply FUN to it. `lapply(changeCols, FUN)` will run through the logical vector, changeCols and apply FUN to each TRUE or FALSE in the vector.

Comment: It iterates the column names, not the individual elements in each column. The example code produces an error with `dfrm[changeCols] <- lapply(dfrm[changeCols], tolower)`. The error says `Error in [.data.frame(dfrm2, , x) : undefined columns selected`.

Comment: This looks like an "index out of bounds" error. Did you create changeCols on dfrm and then use that column on dfrm2 in the `lapply`?

Comment: I simply did this:
`my_list <- c("a", "c", "e", "g"); dfrm2[my_list] <- lapply(dfrm2[my_list], my_low)`

Answer (score 1):

For your first attempt, if you want the assignments to your data frame `dfrm2` to stick, use the `<<-` assignment operator:

```
my_low <- function(x){ dfrm2[,x] <<- tolower(dfrm2[,x]) }
sapply(my_list, my_low)
```

### Demo

Comment: I read that the `<<-` is a very dangerous tool, is that correct?

Comment: @naco It is the parent scope assignment operator, but maybe it makes sense for you to use it here.  It does closely resemble a double-pointed spear; perhaps that is how it got such a bad reputation.